# Slider widget with icon in the label Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-web

It's possible to set Icon in the label of slider widget ?

This widget : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html

```
Slider(
                value: model.feelingContributor,
                onChanged: (double value) {
                  model.setFeelingContributorSlider(value);
                },
                divisions: 4,
                label: "Ressenti",
                min: 1,
                max: 5,
              ),
```

I want to set Icon or Image for all possibilities values in the label. But how i can do ?

Thank you !

Comment: As the doc says you can only set String to a label. You may use Unicode string set emoji if it ok. Like label such as `label = '\u{1F60D}';` . Here is a codepen using [this](https://codepen.io/abhilas-csc/pen/bGVKXgO). If this doesn't solve what you need, then you will have copy the `Slider` widget and change it to render a widget in place of the label.

Comment: oh well ! It's works ! I will try with my personal icon

Comment: Normal Material Icons wont work, but unicode emoji will, as listed [here](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)..

Comment: ok thank you @AbhilashChandran !

Answer (score 0):

The default [Slider](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html) widget doesn't provide the option to modify the Slider thumb. What you can do here is to create a custom Slider thumb and have the image/icon drawn on using Canvas. Here's a [Medium article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliders-demystified-4b3ea65879c) demonstrating how you can create custom Sliders. It demonstrates how you can create a custom thumb by extending on `SliderComponentShape`, and overriding `paint()`. You can then draw the image on Canvas using [paintImage()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65441124).