# Flutter Canvas.drawImage() draws a pixelated image

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter project, I use a `CustomPainter` to draw a custom shape.
In that `CustomPainter`, I need to draw a png image, which is available in my assets folder in multiple sizes, so I can get the right image for the right screen density:

```
assets
   \1.5x
      image.png   // 54 x 54 pixels
   \2.0x
      image.png   // 72 x 72 pixels
   \3.0x
      image.png   // 108 x 108 pixels
   \4.0x
      image.png   // 144 x 144 pixels
   image.png      // 36 x 36 pixels
```

Here is how I load my image, to get an `Image` file:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

Future<ui.Image> getImage() async {
   AssetImage assetImage = AssetImage("assets/image.png");
   ImageStream stream = assetImage.resolve(createLocalImageConfiguration(context));
   Completer<ui.Image> completer = Completer();
   stream.addListener(ImageStreamListener((Imageinfo image, _) {
      return completer.complete(image.image);
   }
   return completer.future;
}
```

And in my `CustomPainter.paint()` function, here is how I draw the `Image`, once loaded:

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
   // ...
   canvas.drawImage(
      myImage, // <- the loaded image
      Offset(20, 20),
      Paint()
   );
}
```

I have two problems:

- the image isn't drawn at the right size (it appears with a size of, let's say, 54 points in a HDPI screen, while the loaded image has a size of 54 pixels... is it a Flutter bug?)
- even if I use `canvas.drawImageRect()` to draw an image of 36 x 36 points, the drawn image is sometimes still glitchy, depending on the image. And yes, I doubled checked the size of the original images.

So what should I do to draw on my `canvas` the right image for the right screen density, so it's drawn properly?

Thanks.

Comment: tried to use `AssetImage`?

Comment: @pskink I was thinking of it, but I don't understand how to use it, do you have an example, by any chance?

Comment: check `ImageProvider` official docs: they have one example

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get it (the problem of being a beginner...). Do you have any link, please?

Comment: @pskink I do, and I was already looking at that webpage, but I'm still struggling. I'll continue my research and get back to you if I'm still stuck.

Comment: OK so my question is: how do I get from an `AssetImage` (which is an `ImageProvider`) to a `dart:ui.Image` that I can draw on a `CustomPainter`?

Comment: in the example they have: `image: _imageInfo?.image, // this is a dart:ui Image object` - they use it [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7891006299/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart#L300)

Comment: @pskink I see: `[54x54]`

Comment: and what is `ImageInfo.scale` ? add `print(image)` before `return completer.complete(image.image);`

Comment: @pskink `ImageInfo.scale` gives me `1.5`, which seems correct, and `print(image)` gives me: `assets/1.5x/image.png [54x54] @ 1.5x`

Comment: ok tried to use (and compare results) of 1) your code 2) `RawImage` 3) `Image.asset` with the same bounds of course? also in your code try top-level `paintImage` function since it is used under the hood by those two widgets

Comment: @pskink I found it!!! I shoud use `paintImage()` instead of `canvas.drawImageRect()`, and the glitches disappear!!

Comment: Is is, but it's after reading this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawImage-class.html , that I tried `paintImage()`

Comment: maybe this is because of:  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/2783f8e2e1/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/decoration_image.dart#L480 ? i mean: `paint.filterQuality = filterQuality;` can you debug `paintImage`?

Comment: @pskink Yup, looks like it's related to `filterQuality`: when I set it to `FilterQuality.none`, I get pretty much the same glitches, when I set it to `FilterQuality.low`, it worls perfectly.

Comment: thanx for info, so you can use your drawImageRect too :-)

Comment: yes, it works, thanks!

Comment: sure, your welcome, merry Xmas :-)

Comment: @pskink you too! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I finally got it to work (thanks @pskink):

Step 1: return the whole `ImageInfo` object, and not only the image:

```
Future<ImageInfo> getImageInfo(BuildContext context) async {
   AssetImage assetImage = AssetImage("assets/image.png");
   ImageStream stream = assetImage.resolve(createLocalImageConfiguration(context));
   Completer<ImageInfo> completer = Completer();
   stream.addListener(ImageStreamListener((Imageinfo imageInfo, _) {
      return completer.complete(imageInfo);
   }
   return completer.future;
}
```

Step 2: use the `ImageInfo.scale` property, and some filtering, to draw the image:

```
@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
   // ...
   paintImage(
      canvas: canvas,
      rect: Rect.fromLTWH(
         20, 20,
         myImageInfo.width / myImageInfo.scale,
         myImageInfo.height / myImageInfo.scale),
      image: myImageInfo.image,                // <- the loaded image
      filterQuality: FilterQuality.low,
   );
}
```